# Access Variable in Python fstring in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have created a variable called item using a fstring which is a combination of other variables:

```html
item = f'{item_id}_{flavour}_{strength}'
```

Is there a way to now access the variables within this fstring to display them in a django template.

At the moment all I have done is pull the whole item string into the template:

```html
<td class="py-3">
   <p class="my-0"><strong>{{ item.product.name }}</strong></p>
   <p class="my-0"><strong>Flavour:
    </strong>{% if item.product.has_flavours %}{{ item.item|upper }}{% else %}N/A{%      endif %}
   </p>
```

Which renders in the html template as:

[front end display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMV5R.png)

I want to access the flavour variable in the string and the strength variable in the string and display them in the template against the Flavour and Strength headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this in the contexts.py (would work the same if your context is in your method in views.py):

```html
 product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=item_id)
            for item, quantity in item_data['items_by_variation'].items():
                flavour = item.split('_')[1]
                strength = item.split('_')[2]
                total += quantity * product.price
                product_count += quantity
                basket_items.append({
                    'item_id': item_id,
                    'quantity': quantity,
                    'product': product,
                    'flavour': flavour,
                    'strength': strength,
                })
```

So for anyone looking for a similar answer. You use the split() function on the string and each part of the string is then given an index, i.e. [0].

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass that through context from views.py

Comment: it is coming through the context already. I can display the whole string. I want to display parts of the string. How do I do that?

Comment: try use  `| truncate()`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the item as a `dataclass`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Item():
    item_id: str
    flavor: str
    strength: str
```

Then you use it like this:

```py
item = Item(
    item_id='item_id_value',
    flavor='flavor_value',
    strength='strength_value',
)
```

Then you can access in the template like this:

```html
<td class="py-3">
   <p class="my-0"><strong>{{ item.product.name }}</strong></p>
   <p class="my-0"><strong>Flavour:
    </strong>{% if item.product.has_flavours %}{{ item.itme_id }}_{{ item.flavor }}_{{ item.strength }}{% else %}N/A{%      endif %}
   </p>
```